# How to install TMS Component Pack 6.0 in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, delphi-xe2, tms

What has to be change in order to install them succesfully in DelphiXE2

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure I just logged into their site, downloaded their installer, and it installed.

From their site:

> Embarcadero released the new RAD Studio XE2! TMS Component Pack is
>   ready for Delphi XE2 & C++Builder XE2. Active registered users can
>   download the latest version v6.1.5.0 now that supports the new XE2
>   IDE's.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but (assuming you have the source for the components) you should be able to open `tmsdefs.inc` and add the following for XE2 support:

```
{$IFDEF VER230}  // Delphi XE2; use VER220 for XE
  {$DEFINE DELPHI2_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI3_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI4_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI5_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI6_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI7_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI9_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI2006_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI2007_LVL}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI_UNICODE}
  {$IFDEF CLR}
    {$DEFINE TMSDOTNET}
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFNDEF BCB}
    {$DEFINE ISDELPHI}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

Then recompile the TMS packages, runtime first, design packages last.

If you don't have the source, you'll have to purchase a new version. `.dcu` files aren't (and have only once been) compatible across compiler versions. (The one exception, IIRC, was Delphi 6 to Delphi 7.)